# Bezier close path not getting filled

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Swift v2.2 and I have drawn a rectangle as shown below which I intend to fill to then display some white text in it. However, I see the path has been closed but the rectangle is not getting filled. Please help and thanks for any input.

**Code**

```
class InstructionArrowBorderView: UIView {

    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 1 {didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    var instructionRectPathColor: UIColor = UIColor(red:13/255.0, green:118/255.0, blue:255/255.0, alpha: 1.0) { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let instructionRectPath = UIBezierPath()
        instructionRectPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY - 50))
        instructionRectPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY))
        instructionRectPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY))
        instructionRectPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY))
        instructionRectPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY))
        instructionRectPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY - 50))
        instructionRectPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY - 50))
        instructionRectPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY - 50))
        instructionRectPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
        instructionRectPath.closePath()
        instructionRectPath.fill()
        instructionRectPathColor.set()
        instructionRectPath.stroke()
    }
}
```

**Layout**

- Cell

  - View (where Bezier's path is drawn)

    - Label (with white text)

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you call `instructionRectPathColor.set()` before `instructionRectPath.fill()`?

Comment: Your not setting a color before calling `.fill()` try just moving it down a line of code and you should see it fill with the same color as your border. Right now it's just filling with the default color which is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are introducing discontinuities into your path. When you say `addLineToPoint` you don't also need to say `moveToPoint`. This is preventing your path from filling correctly. You also want to set the color fill/stroke color then fill/stroke the path.

Your `drawRect` code should be:

```
let instructionRectPath = UIBezierPath()
instructionRectPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY - 50))
instructionRectPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY))
instructionRectPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY))
instructionRectPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY - 50))
instructionRectPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY - 50))
instructionRectPath.closePath()
instructionRectPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
instructionRectPathColor.set()
instructionRectPath.fill()
instructionRectPath.stroke()
```

Which could be written even more concisely as:

```
let instructionRectPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY, width: bounds.maxX, height: bounds.maxY - 50))
instructionRectPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
instructionRectPathColor.set()
instructionRectPath.fill()
instructionRectPath.stroke()
```